# Which Data Structure to use for getting the desired result

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a matrix...

e.g

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
```

Now, I want to take avg of (1,4,7,10) and store it..avg of (2,5,8,11) and store it..avg of ( 3,6,9,12) and store it.

I just want to know which structure I should use for the efficiency.

The number of rows and columns could be increased or decreased.

I thought of arraylist or list. And depending on the number of columns i would take avg. But  I dont think it is optimal solution..

Can you please guide me.

Comment: "I have a matrix" doesn't give much information. How do you get the data? Do you read it from a file? Get it from stdin? Get it from clients connecting to your server? The rate and expected volume of input could have an effect on the decision of which data structure suits you best.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are storing the matrix in an 2D Array like this:

```
int[][] matrix = int[n][m]; //where n is the number of rows and m is the number of columns
```

You could just create an array of size `m` to store all the values in:

```
double[] avg = double[m];
```

(Note: this Array is of type double but you can change it to float or whatever type you use when you calculate your average. `double` is better than `int` though as it will help you keep precision):

It really depends on what you are going to do with the output, but a simple array like that is probably enough for most situations. It will be very easy to store the values because as you are adding the values from column `i` in `matrix`, you can add that avg to index `i` in your `avg` array.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    avg[i] = averageForColumn(i);
}
```

In the above situation, `averageForCoumn(int)` returns the average value for the column at the given index. You don't actually need to create a method to do this though, you could just have another for loop.

Comment: Even if the matrix is an integer type, the average should probably be a `float` or `double`, or it won't be a very accurate average.

Comment: @Boann Thanks! You are absolutely right, I didn't think that far ahead. I edited my answer to have the array be a `double`